# for reCaptcha, the token needs to be sent to backend for validation right?

Tags: authentication, html

So far, I have reCAPTCHA setup in the "submit" button for my login form with v2 Invisible recAPTCHA. But, I have a feeling that the token that I retrieve from Google needs to be sent to my backend (along with my login data) so that the backend can validate it's a valid token before it logs me in. Is this correct?

(I ask this because i have my login form setup in PingFederate, and they are supposed to handle the login)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's not clear of your exact setup based on the question, but the backend indeed does need to do *some* sort of [verification](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) to determine if the captcha was passed. Otherwise, a user could simply send requests directly to your server backend without dealing with the captcha at all, if it was purely a frontend thing.